# Mathjax with Jekyll in Github Pages. Centering an equation on a line

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, mathjax

I have blog which uses Github Pages & is forked from JekyllNow. I use Markdown with Mathjax from https://www.mathjax.org/

As mentioned, I use **JekyllNow** (I don't build locally & deploy).

I have the following

```
$a+b =c$
```

It's obviously not centered when rendered.

So I tried both these options

```
$$a+b=c$$

$$
\begin{align}

a+b = c
\end{align}
$$
```

With these 2 options, when the page loads it's displayed centered for a moment, but within a fraction of a second, the equation gets left aligned again.

These 2 options are displayed centered in VSCode preview.

[image]

However, when the page is rendered on the browser, none of them are centered.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [`mathjax/MathJax` issue 2274](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2274): "GitHub page fails to render `\begin{align}` environment".

> To start, it seems that I should be using `\begin{align}` without the `$$` environment. Whenever I use `\begin{align}` within the `$$` environment, I get this `% <![CDATA[` in the final HTML code. Now this `%` will comment out everything else after it, which caused the problem.
>
> In this new environment of HTML and mathjax, I need to escape the \ symbol through both parts, which means `\\\\` will only lead to `\` in the HTML output. And to get a line break in Latex, I need to type `\` 8 times. This leads to the following markdown code that works.

```html
<script type="math/tex; mode=display">% <![CDATA[
\begin{align}
    \Phi(0,x) = \max_{u \in \mathcal{D}} \bigg[
        \mathbb{E} & \Phi\left(1, 
        x + \int_0^1 \sigma^2(s) \, \zeta(s) \, u_s \, ds
        + \int_0^1 \sigma(s) \, dW_s
    \right) \\\\\\\\
        &- \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sigma^2(s) \, \zeta(s) \,
        \mathbb{E} u_s^2  \, ds
    \bigg].
\end{align} %]]></script>
```

> It appears that the problem has to do with the way the html is formatted for AcademicPages. There are no line breaks in the html, which causes the `CDATA` flag to effectively comment out the `\being{aligned}` portions of code.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I will mark your answer as accepted but will also add a diff answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both these worked.

```
$$\\

a+b = c

\\$$
```

and

```
$$\\

\begin{align}

a+b = c

\end{align}

\\$$
```

Comment: Good catch, well done. Those escaped backslashes are tricky.